# Cannot launch interactive session in Windows IIS Docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, windows-server-2016

I'm using the AWS "Windows Server 2016 Base with Containers" image (ami-5e6bce3e).

Using `docker info` I can confirm I have the latest (Server Version: 1.12.2-cs-ws-beta).

From Powershell (running as Admin) I can successfully run the "microsoft/windowsservercore" container in interactive mode, connecting to CMD in the container:

```
docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore cmd
```

When I attempt to run the "microsoft/iis" container in interactive mode, although I am able to connect to IIS (via browser), I am never connected to the interactive CMD session in the container.

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 microsoft/iis cmd
```

Instead, I simply get:

> Service 'w3svc' started

Using another Powershell window, I can:

```
docker container ls
```

...and see my container running.

Attempting to attach locks up and never returns.

I have since switched regions and found that there are different AMI's on each region:

- us-east-1: ami-d08edfc7
- us-west-2: ami-5e6bce3e

...both of these have the same result.

Relevant links used:

- [AWS announcement and simple Docker example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/run-windows-server-2016-on-amazon-ec2/)
- [MSDN simple Docker example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server)
- [MSDN IIS Docker example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_images)

**Update**

Using the following link I was able to create my own Dockerfile based off the server base and installing IIS and this seems to work fine.

[custom Dockerfile](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2016/04/30/windows-docker-containers/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not an issue with AWS AMI's, it was due to the way the Microsoft IIS Dockerfile was written / being new to Docker.

[Link to Microsoft's IIS DockerFile](https://github.com/Microsoft/iis-docker/blob/master/windowsservercore/Dockerfile)

The last line (line 7):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]
```

[Difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

So since this Dockerfile uses ENTRYPOINT, to launch an interactive powershell session, use the following command:

```
docker run --entrypoint powershell -it -p 80:80 microsoft/iis
```

Note that it seems that the "--entrypoint" flag needs to be after run, as this won't work:

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 microsoft/iis --entrypoint powershell
```

[Here is another reference link regarding ENTRYPOINT and CMD differences](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/)